# Forwarding in jsp - lost session? with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm developing a web app with hibernate and spring mvc. The main problem is, that i've got a jsp page, on which are submit buttons. Every time when user clicks on one of them, string is saved in the list. This works fine, but the problem is, when someone else logs in to my app (2 or more users at one time), then we made "our" list. All users add strings to one, the same  list.

I used, while ago jsf + manage beans and it was ok in that case.

Can anyone tell me what should i do ? I'm out of ideas. What i saw, on first show page is url with parameters (of usersName and usersPassword), then after forms redirect there is just a page name "Tickets.htm".

Here is my code:

Ticket.jsp - page on which users can add all to one list.

```
    <div id="Tickets">
        <c:forEach items="#{TicketList}" var="Ticket" >
            <spring:form method="POST" action="Tickets.htm">
                <input type="Submit" value="${Ticket.name}" name="Button" />
                <input type="hidden" value="${Ticket.name}" name="Hidden" />
                <input type="hidden" value="${WebUser.name}" name="userName" alt="Nothing"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="${WebUser.password}" name="userPassword" alt="Nothing" />
                <br> 
            </spring:form>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>


    <div id="ReservationList" >
        Lista: <br>
        <c:forEach items="#{ReservedTicketList}" var="Ticket" >

            <input type="button" value="${Ticket}" />
            <br> 
        </c:forEach>
    </div>

    <div id="Menu">
        <input type="Submit" value="Zarezerwuj" />
    </div>
```

TicketController - which controlls that page. Method GET shows the TicketList, method POST shows the ReservedTicketList. There are also just a getters and setters.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Tickets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showGet(@RequestParam("userName") String userName,
        @RequestParam("userPassword") String userPassword) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Tickets");

    setWebUser(new WebUser(userName,userPassword));

    String retValue = "";

    Session session = FirebirdHibernateHelper.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "FROM WebLogin W WHERE W.emailaddress =:userName AND W.userpassword =:userPass";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("userName", webUser.getName());
        query.setParameter("userPass", webUser.getPassword());

        List results = query.list();

        WebLogin user = (WebLogin) results.get(0);

        if (!user.getEmailaddress().trim().equals(userName)) {
            model.addObject("message", "Nie ma takiego konta!");
            return model;
        }

        retValue = user.getEmailaddress();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        retValue = "Nie no tak to nie bedzie!  " + ex.getMessage();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    setTicketsFromDB();
    setReservedTicketList(new ArrayList<String>());

    model.addObject("WebUser", webUser);
    model.addObject("TicketList", TicketList);
    model.addObject("message", retValue);

    return model;
}

List<WetBarAssortModel> TicketList;
List<String> ReservedTicketList;

public void setTicketsFromDB() {

    Session session = FirebirdHibernateHelper.getSession();
    try {

        String hql = "FROM WetBarAssortModel W WHERE W.ASSORTTYPE = 'T'";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

        setTicketList((List<WetBarAssortModel>) query.list());

        for (int i = 0; i < getTicketList().size(); i++) {
            //   WetBarAssortModel model = (WetBarAssortModel)result.get(i);
            //     getTicketList().add(model);
            System.out.println("Ticket: " + getTicketList().get(i).getName());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Tickets", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showPost(@RequestParam("Hidden") String name, 
        @RequestParam("userName") String userName,
        @RequestParam("userPassword") String userPassword) {

    System.out.println("POST NAME: "+userName);
    System.out.println("POST PASS: "+userPassword);


    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Tickets");

    getReservedTicketList().add(name);

    model.addObject("WebUser", webUser);
    model.addObject("ReservedTicketList", getReservedTicketList());
    model.addObject("TicketList", getTicketList());
    return model;

}
```

I'll be gratefull for any help.

Comment: Why dont you create a list for each users ?

Comment: Because it should be a internet reservation, and each user can pick more than one ticket. For one user only it works fine, but not for many. Would make difference if i'll use other controller to collect reserved tickets ?

Comment: If everyone adds to the same list, you should use a database for the list not the session.

Comment: Ok, but cant i specify one list for each user? When i did that with jsf + managebean which contains list, it works fine. In this case, it looks like there is only one instance of controller.

Comment: What i actually need, is creating new session on method GET of Tickets page. Can anyone tell me how to do this? 
request.getSession() returns old session.

Comment: I'm actually creating new session every POST method on Tickets page, but i've got still the same problem. Last response shows on every open page. Id session is different after each POST. Anyone knows what's the problem?